# How to introspect the arity of a variadic template template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Consider a hypothetical metafunction `arity`, which takes any metafunction as argument and returns its actual arity.

The following obvious approach is not possible, since by language standards named inner template template parameters are only defined locally.

```
template<template<typename... args> class f>
struct arity
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(args); //ERROR: undefined 'args'
};
```

Not even exhaustive specializations are an alternative, since a template type taking another template type may not be partially specialized with respect to the number of arguments of the inner template.

This brings me to the question, whose answer I fear to be no.

> Is there any reasonable way to introspect the actual arity of a template type?

I don't expect an actual implementation of `arity` to take the form of a template type, such as in the *obvious approach*, that is, anything which may be computed during compile time is acceptable as a "reasonable" solution, as long as it doesn't depend on the actual arguments.

**Note:** for simplicity assume only non-variadic metafunctions are allowed as arguments for `arity`.

Comment: Have your primary template take a `T`, then specialize it with `arity<F<Args...>>` where `Args...` is a template parameter. Then you get the size with `sizeof...(Args)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means you can't pass just the class template, though.

Comment: @0x499602D2 as pointed out by chris, this is unfortunately not "reasonable" in the sense of the original question, for actual args may not be available at the point the arity of a template type is needed.

Comment: @brunocodutra Then it's pretty much impossible AFAIK.

Comment: I doubt this is possible... what would you want it to return if `f` itself was a variadic template?

Comment: @Barry For all that matters "arity" as a concept is not defined for variadic templates, so an error would be acceptable. Please note the footnote I added.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this?

Comment: You don't want solution like `template<template<typename... U> class f, typename... Args>`, yea?

Comment: @ben consider Boost.MPL's quote, defined as a *metafunction class* taking a *metafunction* as parameter. The ability of introspecting the arity of its argument would enable, for instance, implicit partial applications of a *quoted* *metafunction*. Boost.MPL currently solves this by providing numerated versions of quote, i.e. quote1, quote2, etc. I'm looking for an *arity aware* variadic version of quote. For reference, a very simple *arity unaware* version of it I have [here](https://github.com/brunocodutra/mpl2/blob/master/include/boost/mpl2/core/quote.hpp).

Comment: When would you want to know arity but not know the types you want to stuff into the template?  Suppose you have a `template<class...>class` which accepts 2 `std::integral_constant<int,?>` but 3 `std::integral_constant<char,?>` -- logically, it has two different arities!  In a sense, this is a question like "how many arguments does a function object take" -- it will depend on the types of the arguments.

Comment: @Yakk the actual arity of this hypothetical template type would then have to be greater than 2, with at least one parameter necessarely defaulted to some (possibly unspecified) type. Please bear in mind the arity of variadic templates can't possibly be introspected, as pointed out before. That is, the arity of a non-variadic template type is always defined.

Comment: @brunocodutra I can determine if a variardic template can take 1 parameter, by passing it that parameter.  I cannot determine an upper bound on the number of parameters it takes.  My point, however, is that your operation seems seems as misguided as all of the people who want to know the signature of an arbitrary function object and type erase it to a `std::function` with that signature.  Do you have an actual practical problem that inspired your question?  Is finding airity the best solution to the practical problem, or was it just the most available?

Comment: @Yakk I haven't had opportunity to read your answer thoroughly yet, but, with respect to your comments, I'd like to highlight that at first I'm disconsidering variadic templates. Now, the arity of *enumerated* templates is always defined despite it possibly not being *callable* for certain combinations and/or number of arguments. The question itself arose from the fact I realized I couldn't think of a reasonable way to introspect the number of parameters (lets put it this way) of a given template type, nor could I find an answer to that problem. I don't have a specific use for that yet, though

Comment: @brunocodutra Sure: but barring a use case, it seems rather academic doesn't it?  If there is no good use case for it, and it doesn't even have an interesting *structure* to make it interesting in and of itself.  Finding an application, or some interesting structure, would make your question better, basically.

Comment: @Yakk I said I don't have a *specific* use case yet, but solving that problem would certainly come handy in [my attempt to reimplement Boost.MPL on C++11/14](https://github.com/brunocodutra/mpl2). I came across this matter when working on the implementation of [quote](https://github.com/brunocodutra/mpl2/blob/bind/include/boost/mpl2/core/quote.hpp) and [bind](https://github.com/brunocodutra/mpl2/blob/bind/include/boost/mpl2/core/bind.hpp).

Comment: Well, those would be a better question -- "I am reimplementing `quote` in C++11.  Here is my attempt.  Here is where it goes wrong.  I could fix it if I could find the airity of a template, but I don't know how to.  How can I get the airity of a template, or fix my problem with `quote`?"  -- the practical application is central.  The technical problem is secondary, but described.  A solution to either the technical problem, or the practical problem, solves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class...> struct foo;
template<class X> struct foo<X>:std::true_type {};
template<class X, class Y, class Z> struct foo<X,Y,Z>:std::false_type {};
```

under any naive pattern matching, `foo` has an infinite airity.

In practice, it has an airity of either `1` or `3`.

In general, the question "what is the airty of this template" is the wrong question.  Rather, "can these types be passed to this template", or "how many of these types can be passed to this template" is a more useful one.

Looking for the airity of a template is like wanting to extract the signature from a callable object.  If you know how you are going to call an object, asking "can I call it this way?  How about that?" is reasonable; asking "tell me how to call you" is almost always misguided.

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class types>struct types_length;
template<class...Ts>struct types_length<types<Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>
{};

template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};

  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>,void_t<Z<Ts...>>>: std::true_type {};
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct can_apply : details::can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>> {};
```

the above answers the question "can I apply some types to a template".

Now, the longest prefix of a set of types you can apply to a template:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

namespace details {
  template<class types, class=types<>>
  struct pop_back {};
  template<class T0, class...rhs>
  struct pop_back<types<T0>, types<rhs...>>:types<rhs...> {};
  template<class T0, class...Ts, class...rhs>
  struct pop_back<types<T0, Ts...>, types<rhs...>>:
    pop_back<types<T0,Ts...>,types<rhs...,T0>>
  {};
  template<class types>
  using pop_back_t = typename pop_back<types>::type;
}
template<class types>
using pop_back = details::pop_back_t<types>;

namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct longest_prefix {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct longest_prefix<
    Z,types<Ts...>,
    std::enable_if_t<can_apply<Z,Ts...>>
  >:
    types<Ts...>
  {};
  template<template<class...>class Z,class T0, class...Ts>
  struct longest_prefix<
    Z,types<T0, Ts...>,
    std::enable_if_t<!can_apply<Z, T0, Ts...>>
  >:
    longest_prefix<Z,pop_back_t<types<T0,Ts...>>>
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using longest_prefix =
  typename details::longest_prefix<Z, types<Ts...>>::type;

namespace details {
  template<class types>
  struct pop_front;
  template<>
  struct pop_front<types<>> {};
  template<class T0, class...Ts>
  struct pop_front<types<T0,Ts...>>:types<Ts...>{};
  template<class types>
  using pop_front_t=typename pop_front<types>::type;
}
```

similar code that takes a bundle of types and a template, and repeatedly slices off the longest prefix of the bundle of types that can be passed to the template can be written.

(The above code certainly contains typos).

```
template<class types>
using pop_front = details::pop_front_t<types>;
template<size_t n, template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct repeat : repeat< n-1, Z, Z<T> > {};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
struct repeat<0,Z,T> : tag<T> {};
template<size_t n, template<class...>class Z, class T>
using repeat_t = typename repeat<n,Z,T>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class types>
using longest_prefix_tail =
  repeat_t<
    types_length<longest_prefix<Z,Ts...>>{},
    pop_front,
    types<Ts...>
  >;
```

now we can take a template and a bunch of types, and build a bundle of types resulting from applying the template to the longest prefix of the bunch of types in turn.

If we where insane, we could even do backtracking, so that if our template takes 2 or 3 elements, and we feed it 4, it wouldn't try to feed it 3, then fail on having 1 element left -- instead, it could find the longest prefix of each application that allows the tail to be similarly bundled.

Comment: This is very interesting. I haven't thought of this way of testing whether some template may accept a certain number of arguments. Your `can_apply` may thus be used recursively to test whether some template can cope with an increasing number of unspecified arguments, never to be instantiated of course, until it fails, then its arity would be n - 1. Naturally it'll have to be specialized for the variadic case though, which otherwise would recurse the compiler to oblivion. If you'd just update your answer to make this approach clear, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that template types taking template template parameters may not be partially specialized with respect to the arity of its template template parameters, functions may be overload in this manner.

```
template<template<typename> class f>
constexpr std::size_t _arity(){return 1;}
template<template<typename, typename> class f>
constexpr std::size_t _arity(){return 2;}
template<template<typename, typename, typename> class f>
constexpr std::size_t _arity(){return 3;}
//...
template<template<typename...> class f>
constexpr std::size_t _arity(){return 0;}

template<template<typename... args> class f>
struct arity
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = _arity<f>();
};
```

While not ideal, this approach works within reasonable limits and is the closest to a "reasonable" solution that I could think of. However I'm still looking for a pure variadic solution which does not require exhaustive enumeration of functions/types.

Answer (score 0):

It is my approach to this problem. It computes template's arity
by substituting fake types.

`is_subs_success` checks whether it is possible to substitute types to variadic template:

```
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>    
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/void.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>

using namespace boost;

/*
  is_subs_success<F, T...>::value == false
    ==> F<T...> causes a compile error  
*/
template
<
  template<typename... FuncArgs> class Func,
  typename... SubsArgs
>
class is_subs_success {

  typedef int success[1];
  typedef int failure[2];

  // if it's not possible to substitute overload
  template<typename...>
  static failure& test(...);

  // if it's possible to substitute overload
  template<typename... U>
  static success& test(typename mpl::identity<Func<U...> >::type*);

public:

  typedef is_subs_success<Func, SubsArgs...> type;

  static bool const value =
    sizeof(test<SubsArgs...>(0)) == sizeof(success);

};
```

`arity` computes template's arity. It substitutes fake arguments in template. If substitution causes compile error, it continues with one more argument:

```
template
<
  template<typename... FuncArgs> class Func
>
class arity {

  // Checks whether `U` is full set of `Func`'s arguments
  template<typename... U>
  struct is_enough_args;

  // Adds one more argument to `U` and continues iterations
  template<size_t n, typename... U>
  struct add_arg;

  template<size_t n, typename... SubsArgs>
  struct go : mpl::eval_if
      <
        is_enough_args<SubsArgs...>,
        mpl::integral_c<size_t, n>,
        add_arg<n, SubsArgs...>
      > {};

  template<typename... U>
  struct is_enough_args : is_subs_success<Func, U...> {};

  template<size_t n, typename... U>
  struct add_arg {
    typedef typename
      go<n + 1, mpl::void_, U...>::type type;
  };

public:

  typedef typename go<0>::type type;

};
```

This solution works fine only with templates. `arity` never returns `0`.

Simple check:

```
template<typename A>
struct t1 {};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct t2 {};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct t3 {};

int main() {

  BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::bool_<arity<t1>::type::value == 1>));
  BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::bool_<arity<t2>::type::value == 2>));
  BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::bool_<arity<t3>::type::value == 3>));

}
```

Comment: you are relying on ::type being defined for Func<...>, but in general, F<...> need not even be defined.

Comment: Almost there, however the goal is not to find the number of args which are "enough" for substitution, but the total number of args. Note that that these concepts are not equivalent for variadic templates or templates with defaulted args. Leaving variadic templates aside, the way to go is to recursively increase the number of args till it fails, not till it works for the first time.

Comment: @brunocodutra Looks like I misunderstood question. Maybe I'll do something  with it later. Thanks :)